# Asp.NET MVC - DataAnnotations and ModelState.IsValid too invasive into the domain model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, data-annotations, separation-of-concerns

I'm learning ASP.NET MVC from the book [Pro ASP.NET MVC 4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430242361) (which I love so far, by the way).

I'm still in the beginning chapters and it's showing me the `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` namespace attributes, how to sprinkle my model class with these annotations, and then how to use them to check if the model is valid (`ModelState.IsValid` in the `Controller`).

For example:

```
public class GuestResponse
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter your name"]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

...

public ViewResult RsvpForm(GuestResponse guestResponse)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View("Thanks", guestResponse);

    }

}
```

There are a couple things about this that make me uneasy.

1. Why do I want a bunch of attributes littered throughout my domain model? I like my domain model pure and free from any stuff that is implementation specific, and any real world model would be too complex to just use declarative validation like this.
2. Aren't the `ErrorMessage` parameters of the validation attributes somewhat `View` related? Doesn't something like that belong in the `UI` layer? For example...what if due to space constraints I want the mobile version to instead of saying "Please enter your name" say "Name required"? But here it is in my *model*!
3. Why do I want to use `ModelState.IsValid` to determine the status of the model? Shouldn't the model tell me? I understand that `ModelState` is making use of the `DataAnnotations` attributes that *are* in my model, but this seems like it would only work for very simple models. A more complex model might not even have a valid/invalid state, it might just have various stages and states. I'm sort of rambling here, but I don't like the idea of declaratively saying what makes my model valid or invalid.

Any advice, reassurance, or validation of these thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are my answers to your questions:

> 1) Why do I want a bunch of attributes littered throughout my domain model? I like my domain model pure and free from any stuff that is
>   implementation specific, and any real world model would be too complex
>   to just use declarative validation like this.

You absolutely don't want this. What you want is to have a view model which is specifically designed for the purposes of your view. It is this view model that will contain the data annotations, not your domain model. Then the controller will map between the domain model and the view model and will pass the view model to the view. Think of the view model as the projection of one or more domain models. In order to simplify the mapping between your domain and view models you may checkout [`AutoMapper`](http://automapper.org/). The basic rule of thumb is that a view should not be aware of your domain models.

> 2) Aren't the ErrorMessage parameters of the validation attributes somewhat View related? Doesn't something like that belong in the UI
>   layer? For example...what if due to space constraints I want the
>   mobile version to instead of saying "Please enter your name" say "Name
>   required"? But here it is in my model!

Completely agree with you. That's the reason why you should have a view model class which is specifically designed for the purposes of the view.

> 3) Why do I want to use ModelState.IsValid to determine the status of the
>   model? Shouldn't the model tell me? I understand that ModelState is
>   making use of the DataAnnotations attributes that are in my model, but
>   this seems like it would only work for very simple models. A more
>   complex model might not even have a valid/invalid state, it might just
>   have various stages and states. I'm sort of rambling here, but I don't
>   like the idea of declaratively saying what makes my model valid or
>   invalid.

Once again I agree with you. Declarative validation (such as what you get out of the box with Data Annotations) works great for *Hello World* type of applications but once you start writing real world applications with complex validation rules you quickly realize that the declarative approach simply doesn't cut the mustard. It is for this reason that I use [`FluentValidation.NET`](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/). It provides you with a very nice and fluent syntax to express arbitrarily complex validation rules, it [`integrates easily with ASP.NET MVC`](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=mvc&referringTitle=Documentation) and allows to [`unit test your validation rules`](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Testing&referringTitle=Documentation) in complete isolation.

Comment: personally wouldn't say absolutely,  You need to be able to pick and choose when you need a more complex solution.  And again while FluentValidation.NET is very nice it also has its place validating ViewModels or simple domain models.  The validation of complex domain models being the responsibility of the domain itself.

Comment: I agree that using view models adds another layer of complexity but it is definitely the right approach. I have seen so many people starting projects telling that it will be a small application and they don't want to use view models, etc... and then progressively add complexity and end up in a situation where they have to completely scrap everything and start from scratch. IMHO using domain models directly in the views is great for doing some presentations, a hello world kind of applications, but once you get to the business, view models are the only way.

Comment: And as far as validation is concerned, let's take the following example: how do you make conditional validation of dependent properties using data annotations? For example you have 2 properties on your model: City and Zip. Zip will be required only if City has a value. This seems like a pretty common requirement. Which one you would prefer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9277886/29407 Possibility 2 or 3?

Comment: @Alistair FluentValidation (or any other validation framework) should validate ONLY user input (view model). The Domain, anemic or not should care about itself. Personally I use domain value objects in fluent validator to ensure user input is valid. So in a way, the domain still does some of the validation only in a different layer

Comment: In addition to what MikeSW said, you usually have different validation rules on your view models than on your domain models. For example your `CreateUserViewModel` will not have an Id property whereas your `UpdateUserViewModel` will have an Id property and this property will be required. On the other hand your User domain model will have some Id property that represents the primary key or whatever in your data store which has nothing to do with view model validation.

Answer (score 1):

Data annotations is just one way of doing it. You can also use the Fluent API for defining the schema of your database and mapping ER. The annotations are tightly coupled with the front-end jQuery validation codes thus comes in handy and easier.
And yes indeed if you don't want annotations in your business logic you can use view models in your UI layer. That would entirely depend on the scope and size of the application as to the extent of view models that you would end up using.

Here's some blog you can refer to clear up your doubts on EF

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx

Hope this gets you going.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is very dependent on the problem you are attempting to solve.  For instance does your domain contain complex business logic or is the application CRUD-based.  You should attempt to pick the best for the problem you are trying to solve.

1. I guess there are 2 extremes when thinking about these "domain models"  they can simply be data transfer objects between the database and UI, or, they can be complex DDD type object that model the business problem. If they are the former then why not keep them as simple as possible.  On the otherhand complex business domains would be hard to implement well using a 'single' model which is shared between view and db.  In reality you are probably somewhere in the middle.

2 & 3.  Yes they are,  but does that matter for your "note" application,  how about for your shipping app?

Comment: Thanks. Usually the domain models I work with are very complex and contain a lot of business logic.